# Dashes and Spaces in a Phone Number value within database

Tags: mysql, database

I've run into a problem with the current database I'm working on. At the moment they allow all formats of phone numbers. They allow dashes, spaces, and parenthesis. I've changed that to stop accepting it, but now I have another problem. There are 4 years worth of phone numbers with different formats, and when one of the user searches for the phone number, if there is a dash or space, it throws off the query and comes up empty.

I was wondering if there was something I could add to the query to remedy this problem.

So if someone is searching for `3052217171` but the phone number in the database is set to `305 221-7171` or `(305) 221 7171` the query will come up empty. Does anyone have an suggestions?

Comment: Update the existing data to remove those characters. You'll still have problems with `1-555-555-5555` versus `555-555-5555` though.

Comment: You would be better, and probably quicker, to hash together a quick app to fix the data all in one go and be done with it..

Comment: When doing your comparison, you can replace those characters and compare the clean strings. But it's probably better to just write a script to update all existing data.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to avoid doing that but I guess I'll just have to sit down this weekend and sort that out. Thanks for the suggestions guys.